# Tcolorbox - footnotes at end of each page

Tags: tcolorbox

I am using `tcolorbox` to surround my text with a coloured box.

It seems that it cannot place footnotes at the end of each page. Instead, it places them at the end of the entire box. Demonstration below:

[image]

As you can see:

1. Footnote 1 appears at the end of the box (because I inserted it using the proper `\footnote{}` command.
2. Footnotes 2-4 are fake - I manually created them using superscripts in the text, and a combination of `\hrule\`, the `\fakefill` command, and the `enumitem` package.

**How can I achieve something like the 'fake' footnotes I created with the \footnote command? I.e. placed at the bottom of the relevant page (not the end of the whole box).**

In addition, I'd like the footnote text to be left-aligned with the footnote rule, similar to my fake footnotes, rather than indented in (like the actual footnote 1 at the end).

MWE for the picture above:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% look of the page
\usepackage[margin=0.8in, top = 1.3in, bottom = 1.3in, headheight = 0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{50pt}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{\baselineskip} % space between footnotes 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % space at start of paragraph
\setlength{\parskip}{0.14in} % space between paragraphs

% math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% relevant to this question
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*{\fakebreak}{\par\vspace{\textheight minus \textheight}\pagebreak}
\newcommand*{\fakefill}{\par\vspace{\textheight minus \textheight}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[%
parbox = false,
colback = white, colframe = black,
left = 0.5in, right = 0.5in, top = 0.4in, bottom = 0.4in,
height = 9.06in,
sharp corners,
boxrule = 1pt,
breakable,
]

\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}

First sentence.\footnote{Footnote 1.} \\
Second sentence.$^2$

\fakefill

\par\noindent\rule{0.3\textwidth}{0.4pt}
{\footnotesize
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin = 0in, rightmargin = 0in, topsep = 0pt]
\item[$^2$] Footnote 2.
\end{enumerate}
}

\newpage

Third sentence.$^3$\\
Fourth sentence.$^4$

\fakefill

\par\noindent\rule{0.3\textwidth}{0.4pt}
{\footnotesize
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin = 0in, rightmargin = 0in, topsep = 0pt]
\item[$^3$] Footnote 3.
\item[$^4$] Footnote 4.
\end{enumerate}
} 

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't offer a documented setting to change the footnotes to be per page. But the opposite is the case, the documentation states "The `perpage` option of the `footmisc` package is deliberately deactivated inside a breakable box since all footnotes are placed at the end of the box [...]" on page 377.

Answer (score 12):

By default, contents of `tcolorbox` environment is processed in a `minipage` env (set by `capture=minipage`). It is `minipage` that changes the behavior of `\footnote`.

In the following example, I emulate the normal behavior of `\footnote` by

- restoring footnote related counter (from `mpfootnote` to `footnote`), and
- postponing the insertion to `\footins` (normally done in `\@footnotetext`) till the end of first-layer `tcolorbox`.

Currently, all `\footnote`s used in a breakable `tcolorbox` are typeset as if they are used at the end of the last part.

Similar patches can be done on `minipage`, but the key-value system of `tcolorbox` makes the patch softer (less need to modify internal macros) and lighter (shorter codes).

- Update 2023-10-29

  - use collected footnotes before default `/tcb/after` ends the current paragraph, to prevent extra vertical space between adjacent `tcolorbox`es.
  - redirect footnotes in title and lower part as well

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.5in, papersize={10cm, 17cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[hooks]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
% restore footnote internals to those in normal page, not minipage
\def\tcb@restore@footnote{%
  \def\@mpfn{footnote}%
  \def\thempfn{\arabic{footnote}}%
  \let\@footnotetext\tcb@footnote@collect
}

% collect footnote text
\long\def\tcb@footnote@collect#1{%
  % expand \@thefnmark before appending before app to \tcb@footnote@acc
  \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\tcb@footnote@acc\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\footnotetext\expandafter[\@thefnmark]{#1}%
  }%
}

\def\tcb@footnote@use{%
  \tcb@footnote@acc
  \global\let\tcb@footnote@acc\@empty
}
\global\let\tcb@footnote@acc\@empty


\tcbset{
  % restore for every box
  every box/.style={
    before title pre=\tcb@restore@footnote, % just in case
    before upper pre=\tcb@restore@footnote,
    before lower pre=\tcb@restore@footnote,
  },
  % use for layer 1 boxes only
  every box on layer 1/.append style={
    % use \footnotetext befere the default /tcb/after ends the current paragraph
    after pre=\tcb@footnote@use
  }
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
text\footnote{first}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Title\footnote{text}]
  content\footnote{inside tcolorbox}
  \tcblower
  footnote with optional argument\footnote[10]{inside tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
  another box immediately following
\end{tcolorbox}

text\footnote{middle}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  content\footnote{inside second tcolorbox}\par
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    content\footnote{layer \thetcblayer}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
      content\footnote{layer \thetcblayer}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    footnote with optional argument\footnote[20]{inside nested tcolorbox}
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}

text\footnote{last}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow...Really its one of a good suggestion `+1`, is it works if a `tcolorbox` continues from page to page....

Comment: @MadyYuvi The current approach always typesets footnotes in the last part, if a breakable `tcolorbox` is broken actually. It seems the `\insert\footins{...}` used in nested boxes is lost. I'm not sure.

Comment: Using this solution, if I have another box directly following the one with a footnote, more vertical space then usual is added. Can I avoid this somehow?

Comment: @Gargantuar Oh another whatsit issue. Replacing `after app` with `after pre` seems to work. Didn't carefully checked. `\footnotetext` uses `\insert` hence inserts a whatsit, which will occupy a separate paragraph (thus extra vertical space) if surrounded with `\par` (which is the case for two adjacent `tcolorbox`es with default `/tcb/before` and `tcb/after` settings), just like `\color` or hyper links.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Works perfectly in my document, thx.

Comment: @Gargantuar See updated answer. Also added `before title pre=\tcb@restore@footnote, before upper pre=\tcb@restore@footnote`.

Answer (score 0):

The `footnotehyper` package does the job easily. If the hyperlinks are unwanted, just don't use the `hyperref` package.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={10cm, 20cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}% optional
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{footnotehyper}
\makesavenoteenv{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
text\footnote{first}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  content\footnote{inside tcolorbox}\par
  footnote with optional argument\footnote[10]{inside tcolorbox 2}
\end{tcolorbox}

text\footnote{third}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  content\footnote{inside second tcolorbox}\par  
  footnote with optional argument\footnote[20]{inside second tcolorbox 2}
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    content\footnote{layer 2}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
      content\footnote{layer 3}
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}

text\footnote{seventh}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get ```31: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endtcb@savebox ...efalse \color@endgroup \egroup 
                                                  \expandafter \@iiiparbox \...
l.31   \end{tcolorbox}```  This goes away when I comment out the line `\makesavenoteenv{tcolorbox}`, but then the footnotes reappear in the boxes.  Something similar happens when I put the `\end{document}` after the third footnote/before the second box.  How can I fix this?