# Background color for text, allowing footnotes and figures

Tags: tcolorbox, shading

I am writing a book-like set of classroom notes using the memoir documentstyle.
I would like to set off some pieces of text as 'digressions" by using a background color: I've tried two solutions, mimicking an answer to a previous question.
One uses the "framed" package:

```
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{lightgray}
\newenvironment{digression}[1][]%
    {\colorlet{shadecolor}{lightgray}%
        \bigskip%
                \begin{shaded}%
                \begin{flushleft}%
                \textbf{\LARGE{Digression:}\\ \Large{#1}}\\%
        \medskip
    }%
    {%
    \end{flushleft}%
    \end{shaded}%
    \bigskip%
    }
```

The other uses the "tcolorbox" package:

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\newenvironment{digression}[1][]%
{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0pt, sharp corners, parbox=true, breakable]
                \begin{flushleft}%
                \textbf{\LARGE{Digression:}\\ \Large{#1}}\\%
        \medskip
}%
{%
    \end{flushleft}%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    \bigskip%
}
```

Both do the trick as far as getting background color is concerned, but there are two problems that remain for me:  (1) if I use the first version, footnotes disappear;  with the second, they appear within the box rather than at the bottom of the page;  (2) neither one allows figures--the same error occurs in both (not in outer paragraph mode).
I guess the problem (especially (2)) is that this is creating a mini-page (or some analogue).
So my question is: is there a way to introduce a background color which doesn't have these limitations?
I'm not in this instance interested in the bells and whistles which are useful for creating beamer slides; I just want to have a part of my page highlighted with a  contrasting color.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question: for your first issue, might be solved by using \footnotemark and \footnotetext. A MWE helps us to test it before to give you a complete answer.

Comment: About `footnotes` take a look at [Tcolorbox - footnotes at end of each page
](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/558709/1952) you'll find a solution. And respect `figures` is normal that you have problems. `figure` is a floating element, so it's not possible to include it into a `tcolorbox` but you can include non-floating images and add a caption to them with `caption` package.