# Custom footnote outside tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, footnotes, tcolorbox, fancyhdr

## PROBLEM

I have a custom footnote style done with tikz, and inside tcolorboxes this footnote doesn't fit, so I tried that all footnotes inside a tcolorbox environment get out of it with Bernard solution in this question: [Footnote outside theorem environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520067/footnote-outside-theorem-environment)

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\savenotes}
\AfterEndEnvironment{theorem}{\spewnotes}
```

Of course it doesn't work, probably because the custom footnote. I was wondering if it was possible to fix this bug

## CODE

```
%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin=2.75cm, rmargin=2.75cm, tmargin=3cm, bmargin=3cm]{geometry} % margins
\usepackage[hidelinks, linktoc=all]{hyperref} % \href{link}{text}
\usepackage{parskip} % auto new paragraph
\setlength{\parskip}{15pt} % more parskip length
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}

%%%%%%%%%% CUSTOM FOOTNOTE WITH TIKZ %%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{[\arabic{footnote}]} % footnote config
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{\;#1}} % adds space automatically
\newcommand\varfootnote[1] % varfootnote (without number)
{\bgroup\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}\footnotetext[0]{#1}\egroup}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\kern-30pt\tikz{ % custom footnote rule
    \draw[line width=0.4mm](1mm,0)--(15.4,0);
    \draw[line width=0.4mm](0,0) circle (1mm);
    \filldraw(0,0) circle (0.3mm);
    \draw[line width=0.4mm](15.5,0) circle (1mm);
    \filldraw(15.5,0) circle (0.3mm);
   \draw[color=white](0,-0.2);}} % moves the line
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{2pc plus 5pt}

%%%%%%%%%%%% CUSTOM BOX %%%%%%%%%%%

\newtcolorbox{tbox}[1]{title={\centering\large#1}, fonttitle=\bfseries, toptitle=1.5mm, bottomtitle=1.5mm, enhanced, breakable, colback=yellow, colframe=black, boxrule=1pt, arc=2mm, rounded corners, coltitle=white, coltext=black}

%%%%%%%%%% SUPPOSED FIX %%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{box}{\savenotes}
\AfterEndEnvironment{box}{\spewnotes}

%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\footnote{outside footnote}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, colback=yellow, colframe=black, boxrule=0pt, arc=2mm, rounded corners, coltext=black, title=\bf{COLORBOX}, coltitle=white, colbacktitle=black, toptitle=1.5mm,
  bottomtitle=1.5mm]
  
\varfootnote{inside footnote without number}
Random text to fill this up\footnote{inside footnote}

\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{tbox}{title}
custom box\footnote{custom box}
\end{tbox}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick workaround is to use the `\linewidth` to draw the tikz embellishment, and to get everything right use `end_of_paragraph\\[vertical_par_spacing_longitude]` command with some given spacing like `\baselineskip`.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin=2.75cm, rmargin=2.75cm, tmargin=3cm, bmargin=3cm]{geometry} % margins
\usepackage[hidelinks, linktoc=all]{hyperref} % \href{link}{text}
\usepackage{parskip} % auto new paragraph
\setlength{\parskip}{15pt} % more parskip length
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}

%%%%%%%%%% CUSTOM FOOTNOTE WITH TIKZ %%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{[\arabic{footnote}]} % footnote config
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{\;#1}} % adds space automatically
\newcommand\varfootnote[1] % varfootnote (without number)
{\bgroup\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}\footnotetext[0]{#1}\egroup}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\kern-30pt\tikz{ % custom footnote rule
        \draw[line width=0.4mm](1mm,0)--(\linewidth,0);
        \draw[line width=0.4mm](0,0) circle (1mm);
        \filldraw(0,0) circle (0.3mm);
        \draw[line width=0.4mm](\linewidth,0) circle (1mm);
        \filldraw(\linewidth,0) circle (0.3mm);
        \draw[color=white](0,-0.2);}} % moves the line
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{2pc plus 5pt}

%%%%%%%%%%%% CUSTOM BOX %%%%%%%%%%%

\newtcolorbox{tbox}[1]{title={\centering\large#1}, fonttitle=\bfseries, toptitle=1.5mm, bottomtitle=1.5mm, enhanced, breakable, colback=yellow, colframe=black, boxrule=1pt, arc=2mm, rounded corners, coltitle=white, coltext=black}

%%%%%%%%%% SUPPOSED FIX %%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{box}{\savenotes}
\AfterEndEnvironment{box}{\spewnotes}

%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \lipsum*[1]\\[0.5\baselineskip]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, colback=yellow, colframe=black, boxrule=0pt, arc=2mm, rounded corners, coltext=black, title=\bf{COLORBOX}, coltitle=white, colbacktitle=black, toptitle=1.5mm,
        bottomtitle=1.5mm]
        \lipsum[2] whereas \varfootnote{inside footnote without number}
        \lipsum[3]\\[0.5\baselineskip]\footnote{inside footnote}
        
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
    
    \begin{tbox}{title}
        \lipsum[6]\\[0.5\baselineskip] \footnote{\lipsum[7]}
    \end{tbox}
    \lipsum[5]
    
\end{document}
```

---

### **ADDENDUM:**

In a more exhaustive review, he found the solution proposed by muzimuzhi Z, in the post [Tcolorbox - footnotes at end of each page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558922/154390), review it and give your approval to this great solution; For my part, I only removed the definition that made the decoration look very high and I was deleting the kern command, I hope it is helpful and well, sometimes it is only a matter of formulating a question correctly, otherwise the result will be 42.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin=2.75cm, rmargin=2.75cm, tmargin=3cm, bmargin=3cm]{geometry} % margins
\usepackage[hidelinks, linktoc=all]{hyperref} % \href{link}{text}
\usepackage{parskip} % auto new paragraph
\setlength{\parskip}{15pt} % more parskip length
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[hooks]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}

%%%%%%%%%% CUSTOM FOOTNOTE WITH TIKZ %%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{[\arabic{footnote}]} % footnote config
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{\;#1}} % adds space automatically
\newcommand\varfootnote[1] % varfootnote (without number)
{\bgroup\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}\footnotetext[0]{#1}\egroup}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\tikz{ % custom footnote rule %<---- delete kern adjust.
        \draw[line width=0.4mm](1mm,0)--(\linewidth,0);
        \draw[line width=0.4mm](0,0) circle (1mm);
        \filldraw(0,0) circle (0.3mm);
        \draw[line width=0.4mm](\linewidth,0) circle (1mm);
        \filldraw(\linewidth,0) circle (0.3mm);
        \draw[color=white](0,-0.2);}} % moves the line
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{2pc plus 5pt}

%%%%%%%%%%%% CUSTOM BOX %%%%%%%%%%%

\newtcolorbox{tbox}[1]{title={\centering\large#1}, fonttitle=\bfseries, toptitle=1.5mm, bottomtitle=1.5mm, enhanced, breakable, colback=yellow, colframe=black, boxrule=1pt, arc=2mm, rounded corners, coltitle=white, coltext=black}

%%%%%%%%%% SUPPOSED FIX %%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{box}{\savenotes}
\AfterEndEnvironment{box}{\spewnotes}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,theorems}

%%%%%%%%%%%%% WORK SOLUTION GIVEN BY muzimuzhi Z #############
% please check and upvote in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558922/154390
\makeatletter
% restore footnote internals to those in normal page, not minipage
\def\tcb@restore@footnote{%
    \def\@mpfn{footnote}%
    \def\thempfn{\arabic{footnote}}%
    \let\@footnotetext\tcb@footnote@collect
}

% collect footnote text
\long\def\tcb@footnote@collect#1{%
    % expand \@thefnmark before appending before app to \tcb@footnote@acc
    \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\tcb@footnote@acc\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\footnotetext\expandafter[\@thefnmark]{#1}%
    }%
}

\def\tcb@footnote@use{%
    \tcb@footnote@acc
    \global\let\tcb@footnote@acc\@empty
}
\global\let\tcb@footnote@acc\@empty


\tcbset{
    % restore for every box
    every box/.style={
        before upper pre=\tcb@restore@footnote
    },
    % use for layer 1 boxes only
    every box on layer 1/.append style={
        after app=\tcb@footnote@use
    }
}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \lipsum*[1] \footnote{foot note of the principal text} Principal text.
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, colback=yellow, colframe=black, boxrule=0pt, arc=2mm, rounded corners, coltext=black, title=\bf{First Colorbox in page}, coltitle=white, colbacktitle=black, toptitle=1.5mm,
        bottomtitle=1.5mm]
        \lipsum*[2] \varfootnote{inside footnote without number} HERE
        \lipsum*[3] \footnote{inside footnote} HERE.  
        
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
    \,\\
    
    \begin{tbox}{title}
        \lipsum[6]\footnote{\lipsum[3]} HERE \lipsum[4] \footnote{\lipsum[2]}
    \end{tbox}
    \lipsum[5]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought about moving these footnotes outisde the tcolorbox, though I like this result, but is there a way to automatically give this space in case of a footnote exists?

Comment: @Agente156 , I think I found the solution but it's either one way or another, it would be nice to be able to place them at will according to need.

Comment: any solution is welcome