Why does my footnote not appear when marked from a newtcolorbox?
Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558922/49283, I try to have footnotes at the end of my tcolorbox. This works for most of the footnotes, but not for "newContribution". There, while the footnote mark appears in the tcolorbox, the footnote itself does not appear anywhere:
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[margin=.5in, papersize={10cm, 17cm}]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[most,breakable,hooks]{tcolorbox}  % seems better than mdframed
\makeatletter
\global\let\tikz@ensure@dollar@catcode=\relax
\makeatother

\makeatletter
% restore footnote internals to those in normal page, not minipage
\def\tcb@restore@footnote{%
  \def\@mpfn{footnote}%
  \def\thempfn{\arabic{footnote}}%
  \let\@footnotetext\tcb@footnote@collect
}

% collect footnote text
\long\def\tcb@footnote@collect#1{%
  % expand \@thefnmark before appending before app to \tcb@footnote@acc
  \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\tcb@footnote@acc\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\footnotetext\expandafter[\@thefnmark]{#1}%
  }%
}

\def\tcb@footnote@use{%
  \tcb@footnote@acc
  \global\let\tcb@footnote@acc\@empty
}
\global\let\tcb@footnote@acc\@empty


\tcbset{
  % restore for every box
  every box/.style={
    before title pre=\tcb@restore@footnote, % just in case
    before upper pre=\tcb@restore@footnote,
    before lower pre=\tcb@restore@footnote,
  },
  % use for layer 1 boxes only
  every box on layer 1/.append style={
    % use \footnotetext befere the default /tcb/after ends the current paragraph
    after pre=\tcb@footnote@use
  }
}
\makeatother


\newtcolorbox{newContribution}{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    oversize,         % Make the width of text in a tcolorbox the same as \textwidth
    parbox=false,     % 
    colback=white,    % Background color of the box
    colframe=white,   % Frame color
    coltext=black,    % Text color
    boxrule=0pt,      % Frame thickness
    left=0.5\baselineskip,         % Space from left border to content
    right=0pt,        % Space from right border to content
    toprule=0pt,      % Top rule thickness
    leftrule=0pt,     % Left rule thickness
    rightrule=0pt,    % Right rule thickness
    bottomrule=0pt,   % Bottom rule thickness
    top=2pt,          % Reduces space at the top inside the box
    bottom=2pt,       % Reduces space at the bottom inside the box
    boxsep=0pt,       % Common padding of ⟨length⟩ between the text content and the frame of the box
    borderline west={0.7pt}{0pt}{blue}, % Bold line on the left
    before skip=0.2\baselineskip,   % Space between tcolorbox and previous content
    after skip=0.2\baselineskip,    % Space between tcolorbox and following content
}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{
  % restore for every box
  newContribution/.style={
    before title pre=\tcb@restore@footnote, % just in case
    before upper pre=\tcb@restore@footnote,
    before lower pre=\tcb@restore@footnote,
  },
  % use for layer 1 boxes only
  newContribution/.append style={
    % use \footnotetext befere the default /tcb/after ends the current paragraph
    after pre=\tcb@footnote@use
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
text\footnote{first}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Title\footnote{text}]
  content\footnote{inside tcolorbox}
  \tcblower
  footnote with optional argument\footnote[10]{inside tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
  another box immediately following
\end{tcolorbox}

text\footnote{middle}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  content\footnote{inside second tcolorbox}\par
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    content\footnote{layer \thetcblayer}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
      content\footnote{layer \thetcblayer}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    footnote with optional argument\footnote[20]{inside nested tcolorbox}
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{newContribution}
asdf\footnote{my newContribution footnote} wqer
\end{newContribution}

text\footnote{last}
\end{document}


I can't reproduce your issue. All footnotes are displayed at the bottom of the page.

Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611262/footnotes-in-tcolorbox-not-in-the-page-of-the-footnotemark

@JohnKormylo: That does not compile for me.

@jlab: Including the one from "newContribution"? All the other ones appear for me as well, only the one from newContribution does not. I even installed the newest TeX Live 2024 and it did not change for me.

I just recompiled the link and it was fine.  It will probably not be compatible with all the changes in your code.  The main problem with footnotes is that \insert is local.

I didn't see that one was missing. I understood you get no footnote at all. You should maybe clarify your question.

@jlab: I edited the question and hope I improved it accordingly.

@JohnKormylo: I installed TeX Live 2024 today and it compiles now. However, when I add my "newContribution" tcolorbox and try with this, I - again - only get the footnotemark in the main text, but no footnote at the bottom of the page or anywhere else. (I do not know what you mean regarding \insert.)

The problem comes from after skip. It works if you don't set it.

LaTeX use \insert to add new footnotes,  It has the property that the footnote is not added to \footins untill the corresponding text is printed.  BTW, it take two runs for the footnotes to show up when using the aux file.

@JohnKormylo: Is there a way to get the footnote printed on the same page on which the footnotemark is in the main text? When my newContribution box is spanning multiple pages, the footnote is printed on the page on which the newContribution box ends.

after skip sets the key after, the configuration set with after pre=\tcb@footnote@use is lost.
You can maybe replace after skip=0.2\baselineskip by after app=\vspace{0.2\baselineskip} but its not exactly the same as using after skip.
So, you can maybe define a after app skip key that append a skip to the after code (but not replace it)
\tcbset{
  % append skip to /tcb/after code
  after app skip/.style={%
    after app={% copy of /tcb/after skip code from tcolorbox.sty
      \tcb@parfillskip@check%
      \par%
      \ifvmode%
        \nointerlineskip%
        \addvspace{\glueexpr#1-\parskip}%
      \fi%
    }},
}

Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most,breakable,hooks]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
% restore footnote internals to those in normal page, not minipage
\def\tcb@restore@footnote{%
  \def\@mpfn{footnote}%
  \def\thempfn{\arabic{footnote}}%
  \let\@footnotetext\tcb@footnote@collect
}

% collect footnote text
\long\def\tcb@footnote@collect#1{%
  % expand \@thefnmark before appending before app to \tcb@footnote@acc
  \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\tcb@footnote@acc\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\footnotetext\expandafter[\@thefnmark]{#1}%
  }%
}

\def\tcb@footnote@use{%
  \tcb@footnote@acc
  \global\let\tcb@footnote@acc\@empty
}
\global\let\tcb@footnote@acc\@empty

\tcbset{
  % restore for every box
  every box/.style={
    before title pre=\tcb@restore@footnote, % just in case
    before upper pre=\tcb@restore@footnote,
    before lower pre=\tcb@restore@footnote,
  },
  % use for layer 1 boxes only
  every box on layer 1/.append style={%
    % use \footnotetext befere the default /tcb/after ends the current paragraph
    after pre=\tcb@footnote@use
  },
  % append skip to /tcb/after code
  after app skip/.style={%
    after app={% copy of /tcb/after skip code from tcolorbox.sty
      \tcb@parfillskip@check%
      \par%
      \ifvmode%
        \nointerlineskip%
        \addvspace{\glueexpr#1-\parskip}%
      \fi%
    }},
}
\makeatother

\newtcolorbox{newContribution}{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  oversize,         % Make the width of text in a tcolorbox the same as \textwidth
  parbox=false,     %
  colback=white,    % Background color of the box
  colframe=white,   % Frame color
  coltext=black,    % Text color
  boxrule=0pt,      % Frame thickness
  left=0.5\baselineskip,         % Space from left border to content
  right=0pt,        % Space from right border to content
  toprule=0pt,      % Top rule thickness
  leftrule=0pt,     % Left rule thickness
  rightrule=0pt,    % Right rule thickness
  bottomrule=0pt,   % Bottom rule thickness
  top=2pt,          % Reduces space at the top inside the box
  bottom=2pt,       % Reduces space at the bottom inside the box
  boxsep=0pt,       % Common padding of ⟨length⟩ between the text content and the frame of the box
  borderline west={0.7pt}{0pt}{blue}, % Bold line on the left
  before skip=0.2\baselineskip,   % Space between tcolorbox and previous content
  after app skip=0.2\baselineskip,    % Space between tcolorbox and following content
}


\begin{document}

\begin{newContribution}
  a footnote\footnote{in newContribution}.
\end{newContribution}

another footnote\footnote{in document}.
\end{document}



Is there a way to get the footnote printed on the same page on which the footnotemark is in the main text? When my newContribution box is spanning multiple pages, the footnote is printed on the page on which the newContribution box ends.

@Make42 Try something like extras first and middle pre={after pre=\tcb@footnote@use}.

Do you mean in tcbset{ ...  newContribution/.style={ <HERE> ? If so, this did not help. I also tried newContribution/.append style={ <HERE> and \newtcolorbox{newContribution}{ .... <HERE>which also did not help.

@Make42 I meant in the new tcolorbox definition. It was just a suggestion. It seems that after isn't executed at breaking points. You should maybe ask a new question;
